# Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm sorry to ask an overly repeated question, but any of the answer here on stackoverflow really helped me.

I want to use a `FileProvider` to access file to a custom folder. My declaration in the manifest, inside the `<application>` tag:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="my.package.name.provider"
    android:exported="false"            
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

then, in `provider_paths.xml`

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="my_videos" path="MyFolderName/"/>
</paths>
```

(but I tried, instead of `cache-path`, `files-path`, `external-path` and `external-files-path`)

The creation of my files is:

```
public static Uri getUriFromFile(File file, Context context) {
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION;
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), uri, flags);
    return uri;
}

public static File getMyDirectory() {
    File root = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "MyFolderName");
    if(root.mkdir()) Log.e(Consts.TAG, "Directory created");
    return root;
}

...

File outputFile = new File(getMyDirectory(), filename + ".mp4");
videoUri = getUriFromFile(outputFile, this);
```

(and, instead of `context.getCacheDir()`, I tried `context.getFilesDir()`, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `context.getExternalFilesDir("")`)

and finally, I want to retrieve my file:

```
String pathToFile = "/my_videos/filename.mp4";
Uri file = getUriFromFile(new File(pathToFile), context);
```

tried with paths:

```
"/MyFolderName/filename.mp4"
"content://my.package.name.provider/my_videos/filename.mp4"
"content://my.package.name.provider/MyFolderName/filename.mp4"
```

ALL of this tries brought me to this error:

```
Failed to find configured root that contains /my_videos/filename.mp4
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve my file:

None of those are valid paths to the file.

You already have code that gives you a valid path to the file:

```
File outputFile = new File(getMyDirectory(), filename + ".mp4");
```

So, use the code that you already wrote.

Comment: I didn't thought about using the same line again. Fact is that the a third party library returned me that `pathToFile` you see in my question, and I thought "Why using again that line, I already have a path!", but the path wasn't that right.

Using only the filename part of the path with your line worked. Thanks a lot!